# Exporting a geodatabase from postgres

Tags: gdal, postgresql, file-geodatabase, ogr2ogr

I am using GDAL ogr2ogr to export to a file geodatabase from postgres. I keep receiving this error for some layers within my database. Any idea on what is causing this error?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please always include commands and errors in the question body as **text**, so they are legible on all devices and indexable by search engines.

Answer (score 2):

You can probably use the `-unsetFid` flag in your ogr2ogr command if the FID's do NOT need to be retained in the exported FileGDB.

It looks like it's trying to add a feature that has a matching feature ID and the FileGDB probably needs them to be unique, hence the error.